# Read a single line from a one-line text file in CSV format

Tags: perl

I am attempting to read a line from a single-line text file containing three numbers separated by commas. It would be like this:

`40045,47250,400`

I have been fussing with this for several days by trying different combinations I have found on the web.  Below is what I have:

```
open(my $fn, '<', 'prgcfg.txt' or die "Could not open configuration file: '$fn' $!");
my $line = <$fn>;
chomp $line; 
close $fn; 
my ($n,$e,$g) = split /,/,$line[1];
```

The three scalars in the last line are declared above this. It always generates an error regardless of what I try. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your error and warning messages originated from `use strict; use warnings;`, you can eliminate them with the following changes:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fn, '<', 'prgcfg.txt' or die "Could not open configuration file $!";
my $line = <$fn>;
chomp $line; 
close $fn; 
my ($n,$e,$g) = split /,/, $line;
```

The parentheses for `open` are misplaced; in fact, you don't need them at all.

`$fn` is a file handle, not a file name.  Do not try to print the handle in the `die` message.

`$line` is a scalar; don't try to access an element of it as if it were an array.